# C# Invoke Controls.Add

Tags: c#, invoke

I got a control instance My_Control. 
Depending on the current step different sub controls should displayed within that control.

```
public partial class Teach_All : User_Control
{
        /// <summary>
        /// this event gets called on an index change
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        private void Current_index_index_changed(object sender, CIndex_Updater.Index_Changed_Eventargs e)
        {
            //remove old Controll
            int old_index = e.new_index - 1;
            if (old_index >= 0)
            {
                if (InvokeRequired)
                {
                    this.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)(() => Controls.Remove(teach_steps[old_index])));
                }
                else
                {
                    this.Controls.Remove(teach_steps[old_index]);
                }
            }


            //do some stuff....
            //Display next control
            if (InvokeRequired)
            {
                this.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)(() => Controls.Add(teach_steps[e.new_index])));
            }
            else
            {
                this.Controls.Add(teach_steps[e.new_index]);
            }
      }
}
```

However the Control add causes an invalid thread Access exception. So the Invoke does not work as expected. This Event can be fired form any thread, therefore i believe i Need an Invoke.

Could you give me some hints on how to get this invoke to work?

Comment: The control to be added, should be created on the main UI thread as well.  Is that the case?

Comment: the teach_steps list is created in the teach_all contstructor. This constructor is called in from the UI designer. So i'd say that this control was created in the designer  `teach_steps = Generate_User_Contol_List();`.  Generate User_Controll does generate every user control and adds them to the list